# Builder pattern : How does private constructor of object to be built work?

Tags: c++, builder

1. List item

Query 1: If we hide the constructors of A, how does ABuilder build A ? This code is as per an example referred to in `Design Patterns in Modern C++`.

Query 2 : If we wish to lazy initialize an object using Builder pattern, do we need to allocate the A object inside ABuilder on heap ? Is it a case well documented with an example ?

Query 3 : What is the operator `operator A()` inside the builder class ? is it a typecasting operator ? How does it get called on the builder class ?

```
struct A
{
    int x;

    static std::unique_ptr<ABuilder> build()
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<ABuilder>(new ABuilder());
    }

    std::string str() const {
        std::cout << "str\n";
    }

    private: // hide all constructors
    A() {}
    A(int x)
    : x(x) {}
};

struct ABuilder
{
    operator A() const { return root; }
    A root;
    // other operations omitted
    ABuilder() {}

    ABuilder& x(int x)
    {
        root.x = x;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    A e = A::build()
     ->x(2);
   std::cout << e.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It works because at the point the object is being created  (in the call to build), the constructor is in scope. Remember that in c++ access is managed on a type-basis, not on an object-basis.

Inside a member function (static or not) you have access to all public and protected members of 'this' (for non-static functions) as well as any other object of the type that is in-scope. You also have such access to any friends that are in scope.

2) It is possible to lazy-initialize a single object of a type and have it live on the stack by having a function static object, this is a common pattern for singleton types:

```
class example
{
  example & get_object() {
    static example object;
    return object;
  }
```

private:
      example() = default;
    };

object will not actually be initialized until get_object() is called for the first time.

Comment: Query 1 : I get the error `g++ builder.cpp -std=c++11
builder.cpp: In constructor ‘ABuilder::ABuilder()’:
builder.cpp:17:1: error: ‘A::A()’ is private`. How does the compiler identify A is being built in the call to build ? Query 2 : The function static object will be shared across different instances of the container class. Are we putting unnecessary constraints ?

Comment: (1) I assumed that that OP references to "ABuilder" were mistaken, that "A" was intended, or that the type was supposed to be named "ABuilder" rather than "A". (2) If get_object is the only place that an instance of example is created then there won't be any other instances. I probably should have deleted copy-construct and copy-assign along with move-construct and move-assign to make that explicit.

Comment: (1) In my opinion, ABuilder should be friend class of A. Then it should work. (2) Suppose an object of A is housed in a class TestClass. One might have multiple instances of class A. We would not want to share A across multiple TestClass instances